# RemoteAction not invoking

Tags: remote-action

I have the following visualforce page coded. However there is a weird scenario in which one my of remote action in the getRemoteAccount(). Sometimes this function is being called.

```
</script>

        </head>
        <body><div class="waitingSearchDiv" id="loading" style="background-color: #FFFFFE; height: 100%;opacity:0.65;width:100%;"> 
                            <div class="waitingHolder" style="top: 50%; width: 100%;">
                               <span class="waitingDescription"><apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Resource.PIPResource,'/css/images/LoadingImage.gif')}"/></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      <div class="main">


    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table" width="100%" align="center" border="0" >
           <tr width="100%">
               <td width="30%" align="left" >
                   <table class="table borderless">
                       <tr>
                           <td>Project</td>            <!-- INC2745476 -->
                           <td><apex:outputlink value="/{!project.Id}" style="font-weight: bold; color: blue;text-decoration: underline;">{!project.Name}</apex:outputlink></td>
                           <td>Hotel Name</td>            <!-- INC2745476 -->
                           <td><apex:outputText value="{!project.Hotel_Name__c}"/></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td>Inn Code</td>            <!-- INC2745476 -->
                           <td><apex:outputText value="{!project.Hotel_Inn_Code__c}"/></td>
                           <td>Location #</td>            <!-- INC2745476 -->
                           <td><apex:outputText value="{!project.Hotel_Location__c}"/></td>                                                                                  
                       </tr>
                   </table>
                </td>
                <td align="left"  width="40%">
                    <table>
                        <tr class="spaceUnder">
                            <td style="display: inline-block;">Visit&nbsp;&nbsp; <select id="VisitType" name="VisitType" class="VisitType" data-areastorage="{!strProjectId}_visitSITE"><option value="Select">Select</option>
                                    <option value="DefaultVisit">Default Visit</option>
                                    <option value="First Visit">First Visit</option>
                                    <option value="CC1">CC1</option>
                                    <option value="CC2">CC2</option>
                                    <option value="CC3">CC3</option>
                                    <option value="CC4">CC4</option>
                                    <option value="Final Visit">Final Visit</option>
                                    <option value="Courtesy Visit">Courtesy Visit</option>
                                    <option value="Model Room Visit">Model Room Visit</option>
                                    <option value="Desktop Extension">Desktop Extension</option>
                                </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                Visit Date&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="date" name="{!strProjectId}_visitdate" id="visitdate" style="height: 20px;"></input></td>



                       </tr>

                       <tr>
                           <td>
                                <input type="radio" name="visitStatus" value="1" id="r1">
                                  <span style="color: green;font-size:10px; font-weight: bold;"><b>GREEN</b></span>
                               </input>&nbsp;
                               <input type="radio" name="visitStatus" value="2" id ="r2">
                                  <span style="color: #FFD700;font-size:10px; font-weight: bold;"><b>YELLOW</b></span>
                               </input>&nbsp;
                               <input type="radio" name="visitStatus" value="3" id ="r3">
                                  <span style="color: red;font-size:10px; font-weight: bold;"><b>RED</b></span>
                               </input>&nbsp;
                           </td>                                                                                 
                       </tr>
                   </table>
              </td>
               <td>
                   <table style="border: 1px solid black;border-style: solid;border-color: #B2B2B2;">
                   <tbody><tr><td valign="top"><span style="font-size:25px; font-weight:bold; color:green;">* </span></td><td style="padding-left:3px;">90 % Complete at the time of visit</td></tr>
                   <tr><td valign="top"><span style="font-size:25px; font-weight:bold; color:#FFFF33;">* </span></td><td style="padding-left:3px;">Not done to contract, but significant progress has been completed and should be less than 3 months delayed</td></tr>
                   <tr><td valign="top"><span style="font-size:25px; font-weight:bold; color:red;">* </span></td><td style="padding-left:3px;">Project is off-track with a delay of 3 months or more, OR, Project is in Default</td></tr>
                   </tbody></table>
               </td>
            </tr>
        </table>           
    </div>

<div id="menu"><input type="checkbox" id="completeditems" data-percent="100"> <b> Completed Items</b></input></div>

 <div class="tabbable boxed parentTabs" id="tabsdata">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="ulTab"></ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="tabcontent"></div></div>
<div class="table-responsive border">
<table class="table" style="width:100%"><tbody><tr><td style="width:35%"></td><td style="width:65%">
                    <!-- <input class="btn" id="viewProject" name="viewProject" type="button" value="View All Projects"></input> -->
                    <input class="btn" onclick="window.location.href='/{!project.Id}'" id="backProject" name="Back" type="button" value="Back to Project"></input>
                    <input class="btn" id="submitItem" name="Submit" type="button" value="Submit"></input>
                    </td></tr></tbody></table>
                    </div>


</div>
        <div id="result" class="hide"></div>

        <script>


  $(document).ready(function () {




                getRemoteAccount();

        // function to fetch server data
       function getRemoteAccount() {
             var ProjectId = '{!strProjectId}';

             Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                        '{!$RemoteAction.SiteVisitFormRemoteActionController.getProjectItem}',
                        ProjectId, 
                function(result, event){

                $('#result').append(result);
                       var jsonValue = $("div#result").text();
                       var sitevisitObj = $.parseJSON(jsonValue);
           //alert(jsonValue);
            var now = new Date();

    var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

    var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day);


   $('#visitdate').val(today);
                 function removeSplChars(str){
     var _tempStr = str.replace(/ /g,'');
     _tempStr = _tempStr.replace('\'','');
     _tempStr = _tempStr.replace(':','');
      _tempStr = _tempStr.replace('/','');
      _tempStr = _tempStr.replace('&','');
      _tempStr = _tempStr.replace('\(','');
      _tempStr = _tempStr.replace('\)','');
     return _tempStr;
 }
```

Comment: I suggest you be more precise about when this does and does not work and what symptoms you see. Have checked the JavaScript console for errors when it doesn't work?